# How to get the device and hardware icons from iron icons list in polymer js?

Tags: angularjs, polymer-2.x, polymer-starter-kit, polymer-3.x

Thanks in advance.
In google polymer 3, I used below link to get the icons
https://npm-demos.appspot.com/@polymer/iron-icons@3.0.1/demo/index.html
I can use the images from icons list and unable to use another images from Av, Communication, devices etc.
Can anybody please help me on this.

Comment: did u fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you would show some code. To be precise the bit of code where you imported the icons and use them. I believe you might have imported not all icon -sets

However, the best way to use the icons provided by Polymer is to create a file which includes only the icons you actually going to use. This will reduces load time and makes the icons generally more accessible.

**Example:** 
This Polymer3 Element is called custom-icons.js

```
import '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import '@polymer/iron-icon/iron-icon.js';
import '@polymer/iron-iconset-svg/iron-iconset-svg.js';
const $_documentContainer = document.createElement('template');

$_documentContainer.innerHTML = `<iron-iconset-svg size="24" name="custom-icons">

 <svg>
    <defs>
        <g id="menu">
            <path d="M3 18h18v-2H3v2zm0-5h18v-2H3v2zm0-7v2h18V6H3z"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="arrow-back">
            <path d="M20 11H7.83l5.59-5.59L12 4l-8 8 8 8 1.41-1.41L7.83 13H20v-2z"></path>
        </g>
    </defs>
 </svg>

</iron-iconset-svg>`;

document.head.appendChild($_documentContainer.content);
```

Comment: <iron-icon  icon="communication:phone" name="view2" ></iron-icon>

Comment: In the above line communication:phone is not supporting

Comment: <iron-icon  icon="home" name="view1"   ></iron-icon>  This is working fine but  icon="communication:phone"  doesn't work

Comment: Well you haven't imported the communication icons. Either way I would recommend you to switch to the example I've posted above. You can also take a look at the Polymer3 starter kit they do it the same way.

Comment: I have imported that's way it is working  icon="home" .

Comment: Pls help me on this why   "icon="communication:phone""  this is not working.

Comment: Add code to your post otherwise there isn't much I can do

Comment: */

import { PolymerElement, html } from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import { setPassiveTouchGestures, setRootPath } from 
import '@polymer/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.js';
import '@polymer/iron-icon/iron-icon.js';
import '@polymer/iron-icon/iron-icon.js'
import '@polymer/iron-iconset-svg/iron-iconset-svg.js';  <a href="[[rootPath]]view1"> <iron-icon  icon="home" name="view1"   class="iconsSetup"></iron-icon></a>
     <a href="[[rootPath]]view2"> <iron-icon  icon="communication:phone" name="view2" class="iconsSetup"></iron-icon></a>

Comment: I dont have git access so I am unable to share the coded. Pls check the above lines.

Comment: https://npm-demos.appspot.com/@polymer/iron-icons@3.0.1/demo/index.html Pls refer this iron icons only In that I want Av, device etc icons

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code up there. Because I can't read it without formatting. You are importing iron-icon twice. But you should import iron-icons

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import explicitly other icon sets as:

```
import {PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import {html} from '@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/html-tag.js';

import '@polymer/iron-icon/iron-icon.js';
import '@polymer/iron-icons/iron-icons.js';
```

here below are for the  Av, Communication, devices icons:

```
import '@polymer/iron-icons/av-icons.js';
import '@polymer/iron-icons/communication-icons.js';
import '@polymer/iron-icons/device-icons.js';
```